# {structure:page_uri_for:X} and parse order

Tags: structure, parse-order

I need to send a page URL as a parameter into a plugin. So I have a global var called lv_shop_page (early parsing) which is an entry ID to a page which I'm passing to structure's `{structure:page_uri_for:X}` function. When I just output `{structure:page_uri_for:{lv_shop_page}}` it comes out with the proper URL but when I put this into the parameter of a plugin like so:

```
{exp:someplugin
parse="inward"
page="{structure:page_uri_for:{lv_shop_page}}/blah/blah"}
```

I get

```
{structure:page_uri_for:470}/blah/blah
```

I know this is a parse order problem, is there any way round this so I can make `{structure:page_uri_for:X}` parse earlier than my plugin? Or maybe another workaround using stash or embeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{structure:page_uri_for:XXX}` variable is parsed late, after template parsing has occurred (using the `template_post_parse` hook). In other words, too late to be used as a tag parameter in your plugin. However, there is an undocumented Structure tag you can use instead of the `{structure:page_uri_for:XXX}` variable: `{exp:structure:page_slug}`.

```
{exp:someplugin
    parse="inward"
    page="{exp:structure:page_slug entry_id='{lv_shop_page}'}/blah/blah"
}
```

You may have to you an embed and/or Stash to get the parse order right, but this should be possible.